# Why does Animation not work in Avalonia? it said Unable to cast object of type 'Avalonia.Animation.AnimatorKeyFrame' to type 'Avalonia.IStyledEleme;

Tags: animation, avalonia

I want to make a animation like

```
<Style.Animations>
        <Animation Duration="0,0,1" PlaybackDirection="Normal" FillMode="None">
            <KeyFrame KeyTime="0.5">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{TemplateBinding Width}" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{TemplateBinding Height}" />
            </KeyFrame>
        </Animation>
    </Style.Animations>
```

but it tell me Unable to cast object of type 'Avalonia.Animation.AnimatorKeyFrame' to type 'Avalonia.IStyledEleme;

How can I Solve the problem?

Comment: Any one can help me!!

Comment: Have you tried using values directly instead of `TemplateBinding`? The issues is probably somewhere else in the code. Also this animation would do nothing, since you just set the same values in the middle of its duration.